# bootstrap textbox going out from span

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, forms, grid-system

I am using bootstrap for the website .  I am facing one strange problem the textbox is coming out from the span i defined .

Here is the code
                
                
                
                
                
                 Sign up
                
                
                
When i remove the span6 from this line 
                 
the textbox comes inside the div .

[image]

Comment: Are You floating those divs? There has to be some other styling because barebones this works: http://jsfiddle.net/Y6QAm/

Comment: i have this <div class="span6 animated fadeInRight delay3s"> above of it

Comment: can add a screen shot of the output you are having?

Comment: i added the image . @KevinBowersox so u think anyother css is causing this issue ?

Comment: @KevinBowersox I just tried your fiddle and it's doing exactly the same as shown in the picture, so just to clarify it's not working as you think. Resize your window so you can see what I mean.

Comment: @sulfureous Didn't try resizing.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a fiddle of the clean code running in bootstrap... you can see the issue is gone, now it's a matter of just seeing how you want it to look to help you modify the code to reach that aspect with proper bootstrap usage.

### [The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sulfureous/WfCcv/)

I can see that you are not using bootstrap properly with it's 12 grid column system. Maybe you need to add a picture of your end view so we get a better idea on how to help you.

You care using input `type="textbox"` which isn't really valid. I think you are looking for input `type="text"`

Controlling the width of those text boxes is pretty simple by using `.span#` (in # goes your span number) you can set the text inputs to be `span12` and it would make them the full width of their parent container.

### Here is your code cleaned up a bit

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">
    <div class="span4">
      <input type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
      <input type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
      <button id="signup">Sign up</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please also notice that your button and everything was collapsing into eachother because your numbers for the spans were not adding up properly. Having your submit button in a `span1` was just too small to contain the button.

Ultimately the answer to this will be based on exactly how you want this area to look, while also considering that on smaller screen sizes things will stack and be a bit different.

I will update my answer when you update your question to show us exactly the effect you are looking for.